# Javascript trick to omit class

Tags: javascript, class

I have got a recursive function of calculating a matrix determinant, but in the argument of it I have a class name, and later on I'm using that function, but this time I need instead of an argument as a class name, I need it to simply a name of a matrix.

Or can I somehow add a class to my smaller matrix?Or how can I trick this.Would be grateful.

```
function create2Darray(clname)
{
    //creates a 2d array of an array returned by the function getElementsByClassName;
    var A = document.getElementsByClassName(clname);
        var arr = new Array();
    var rows = Math.sqrt(A.length);
    for(var i = 0;i < rows; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new Array();
        for(var j = 0; j < rows;j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = A[i*rows + j].value;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

function determinant (matrixClass) 
{
    var matrix = create2Darray(matrixClass);
    var det = 0;
    if(matrix.length == 1)
    {
        return matrix[0][0];
    }
    else if(matrix.length == 2)
    {
        return (matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]);
    }

    var smaller = new Array();//creating an empty array for a matrix minor;
    for(var k = 0;k < matrix.length; k++)
    {
        smaller[k] = [];
        for(var l = 0;l < matrix.length; l++)
        {
            smaller[k][l] = [];
        }
    }       

    for(var i = 0;i < matrix.length; i++)
    {
        for (a = 1; a < matrix.length; a++) 
        {
            for (b = 0; b < matrix.length; b++) 
            {
                if (b < i) 
                {
                    smaller[a - 1][b] = A[a][b];
                } 
                else if (b > i) 
                {
                    smaller[a - 1][b - 1] = A[a][b];
                }
            }
        }
        if (i % 2 == 0) 
            s = 1;
        else 
            s = -1;

        det += s * A[0][i] * (determinant(smaller));
    }
    return (det);
    alert(det);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you need different behavior in determinant function depending on whether you pass class or name to it.

How about adding second parameter that will say what it is?

```
function determinant(matrixClassOrName, type) {
    if (type == "class") {
        //logic for class
    }
    else if (type == "name") {
        //logic for name
    }

}
```

Although you could just use two different functions in this case.

Comment: if(type == 'class'){
  var matrix = create2Darray(matrixClass);
 }
 else if(type == 'name'){
  matrixClass = new Array();
  var matrix = matrixClass;
 }     would smth like that work?

Comment: i think instead of 'matrixClass = new Array(); var matrix = matrixClass;' you can do just 'var matrix = new Array();'